# How to detect plane surface using ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit, measure

I'm creating an app for measuring height of an object using ARKit. For small objects like bottle , pen and monitor it shows almost accurate result. but when am try for some large objects ie height of a men, height of a door its shows different result for each measuring. I think its because of the surface plane detection.

is there any better solution for detecting plane? or any other option for finding height?

Also is there any info about Vision framework with ARKit?

Comment: Welcome Sachu. The best way to get help here is for you to show some of the code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Review the following code, I think it'll help you to find out how the measurement works:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var aimLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var notReadyLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    let session = ARSession()
    let vectorZero = SCNVector3()
    let sessionConfig = ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration()
    var measuring = false
    var startValue = SCNVector3()
    var endValue = SCNVector3()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupScene()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        session.pause()
    }
    func setupScene() {
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.session = session
        session.run(sessionConfig, options: [.resetTracking, 
                                             .removeExistingAnchors])
        resetValues()
    }
    func resetValues() {
        measuring = false
        startValue = SCNVector3()
        endValue =  SCNVector3()
        updateResultLabel(0.0)
    }
    func updateResultLabel(_ value: Float) {
        let cm = value * 100.0
        let inch = cm * 0.3937007874
        resultLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f cm / %.2f\"", cm, inch)
    }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.detectObjects()
        }
    }  
    func detectObjects() {
        if let worldPos = sceneView.realWorldVector(screenPos: view.center) {
            aimLabel.isHidden = false
            notReadyLabel.isHidden = true
            if measuring {
                if startValue == vectorZero {
                    startValue = worldPos
                }
                endValue = worldPos
                updateResultLabel(startValue.distance(from: endValue))
            }
        }
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        resetValues()
        measuring = true
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        measuring = false
    }
}
```

As you can see there's no `.planeDetection` structure.